# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[x] \backslash \langle x^2-3 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

I want to proof that show that $\mathbb{Q}[x] \backslash \langle x^2-3 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ here is my attempt using the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms.

Let's define $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ by $\phi(f(x))=f(\sqrt{3})$ note that this represents a homomorphism of rings because, given $f(x)$, $g(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

$$\phi(f(x)+g(x))=(f+g)(\sqrt{3})=f(\sqrt{3})+g(\sqrt{3})=\phi(f(x))+\phi(g(x))$$

And $$\phi(f(x)g(x))=(fg)(\sqrt{3})=f(\sqrt{3})g(\sqrt{3})=\phi(f(x))\phi(g(x))$$

Thus it is a ring homomorphism. We have to

ker($\phi$)=$\{f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]: f(\sqrt{3})=0 \}=\langle x^2-3 \rangle$

Thus, the map $\mu:\mathbb{Q}[x] \backslash \langle x^2-3 \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ given by $\phi(x)=\mu(f(x)+ \langle x^2-3 \rangle)$ is an isomorphism of rings, and therefore $\mathbb{Q}[x] \backslash \langle x^2-3 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Is this correct? what can I do better? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your idea looks good to me! The one thing is that you want to be careful with your notation towards the end. In particular, I don't think the line "$\phi(x) = \mu(f(x) + \langle x^2 - 3 \rangle)$" doesn't quite work in light of your previous definitions. But it is the case $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle x^2 - 3 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ using the ring homomorphism you outlined and the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: If you want to express an isomorphism explicitly, then rework your map $\mu$ to define it the way I think you had intended.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: You say $\Bbb Q[x]\backslash \langle x^2-3\rangle$, but I think you mean $\Bbb Q[x]/ \langle x^2-3\rangle$. The operation is supposed to emulate division, not be a difference of sets. (And yet we never really write $\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{ \langle x^2-3\rangle}$ for some reason.)